# Linear mixed modelling variance

Tags: mixed-model, variance, linear

I am a beginner in lmm and there is this question that keeps coming back by reading the book by Snijders and Bosker Multilevel Analysis - why do they always say that $U_{0j}$ and $U_{1j}$ are not directly observed but are latent variables?

E.g. I have measured several classes and I can calculate their average success (their group intercepts) (let's say that slopes are fixed, but intercepts are random) - $\gamma_{0j}$. From this averages I calculate the grand average $\gamma_{00}$ and then $U_{0j} = \gamma_{00}-\gamma_{0j}$. If that is so, I can't understand why they say that $U_{0j}$ is a latent variable...